# canvas.drawArc() using Stroke Paint very imprecise

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a thick (~40dp) partitioned circle using the canvas.drawArc() method and a Paint with STROKE set as style.

But this onDraw() implementation

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    p.setStrokeWidth(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.circle_stroke_width));
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    RectF rect = new RectF(
            getWidth()*0.1f,
            getWidth()*0.1f+200,
            getWidth()*0.9f,
            getWidth()*0.9f+200
    );

    canvas.drawArc(rect, 0, 180, false, p);
    canvas.drawArc(rect, 180, 180, false, p);

}
```

gives me this result

[Link to the result picture because I don't have any reputation yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebcl0.png)

Is there a way to prevent these gaps when connecting multiple arcs using this method?

Comment: I don´t think you can avoid this by drawing two arcs. Is there a certain reason why you don´t use drawCircle() ?

Comment: I actually want to use different colors on different segments, I just wanted the code passage to be shorter.

Comment: I've found the same thing! The outside edge needs like 1.0f more sweep angle - but that makes the inside edge curl around too far.

Comment: I was hoping that using `Paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);` would have fixed it - but no luck :-(

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. In the Android Studio preview window my custom View was drawing fine, but when running it on my HTC One M8 with Android 5.0.2 there was a slight gap at 0 degrees.

I set the view to use software rendering and it fixed the issue:

```
myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Hardware Rendering:                                 
Software Rendering:

[image: gap] [image: no gap]